# CannotResolveClassException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.RandomCSVDataSetConfig

Tags: java, maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am building a maven project to execute performance testing for multiple web services, and this is following to [jmeter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin).

However I ran into an issue which is basically that maven can not find the `RandomCSVDataSetConfig` class. in which I included in my pom file.

Please share you insight if you have any idea why this is happening.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>automation.ares</groupId>
    <artifactId>vu-ares</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.blazemeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-random-csv-data-set</artifactId>
            <version>0.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--specifying this will make the build fail if the fail percentage is more than that.-->
                    <errorRateThresholdInPercent>10</errorRateThresholdInPercent>
                    <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
                    <propertiesJMeter>
                        <BUILD_TAG>${project.version}</BUILD_TAG>
                        <!--Specifying the number of threads passed to the test plan-->
                        <threads>7</threads>
                        <duration>30</duration>
                    </propertiesJMeter>
                    <jmeterExtensions>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.6</artifact>
                    </jmeterExtensions>
                    <excludedArtifacts>
                        <exclusion>org.slf4j:slf4j-nop</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>avalon-framework:*</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>org.apache.tika:*</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>excalibur-datasource:excalibur-datasource</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>excalibur-instrument:excalibur-instrument</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>excalibur-logger:excalibur-logger</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>excalibur-pool:*</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b5</exclusion>
                    </excludedArtifacts>
                    <jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m</argument>
                            <argument>-Xmx1024m</argument>
                            <argument>-Xms1024m</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>check-results</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

the logs looks like:

```
2019-02-21 10:56:50,616 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US
2019-02-21 10:56:50,647 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: user.properties
2019-02-21 10:56:50,648 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading system properties from: system.properties
2019-02-21 10:56:50,652 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2019 The Apache Software Foundation
2019-02-21 10:56:50,653 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Version 5.1 r1853635
2019-02-21 10:56:50,653 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_191
2019-02-21 10:56:50,653 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
2019-02-21 10:56:50,653 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.name=Mac OS X
2019-02-21 10:56:50,653 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.arch=x86_64
2019-02-21 10:56:50,653 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.version=10.13.6
2019-02-21 10:56:50,653 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8
2019-02-21 10:56:50,653 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.awt.headless=true
2019-02-21 10:56:50,653 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =1029177344
2019-02-21 10:56:50,653 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Available Processors =8
2019-02-21 10:56:50,657 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States)
2019-02-21 10:56:50,657 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States)
2019-02-21 10:56:50,657 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeterHome=/Users/xxxx/bitbucket/vuares/target/jmeter
2019-02-21 10:56:50,657 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.dir  =/Users/xxxx/bitbucket/vuares/target/jmeter/bin
2019-02-21 10:56:50,657 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: PWD       =/Users/xxxx/bitbucket/vuares/target/jmeter/bin
2019-02-21 10:56:50,664 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: IP: 10.66.181.102 Name: vuitm08phtd7.local FullName: 10.66.181.102
2019-02-21 10:56:50,667 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.outputdir' to:'/Users/xxxx/bitbucket/vuares/target/jmeter/reports/StudentServiceK8sTestPlan'
2019-02-21 10:56:50,669 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='/Users/xxxx/bitbucket/vuares/target/jmeter/bin'
2019-02-21 10:56:50,674 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/Users/xxxx/bitbucket/vuares/target/jmeter/testFiles'
2019-02-21 10:56:50,824 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2019-02-21 10:56:50,845 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2019-02-21 10:56:50,850 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 5.0
2019-02-21 10:56:50,856 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: /Users/xxxx/bitbucket/vuares/target/jmeter/testFiles/StudentServiceK8sTestPlan.jmx
2019-02-21 10:56:50,931 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-02-21 10:56:50,931 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-02-21 10:56:50,931 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-02-21 10:56:50,932 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-02-21 10:56:50,932 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2019-02-21 10:56:50,932 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2019-02-21 10:56:50,948 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Error in NonGUIDriver
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/Users/xxxx/bitbucket/vuares/target/jmeter/testFiles/StudentServiceK8sTestPlan.jmx'. 
Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.RandomCSVDataSetConfig

 Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/com.blazemeter.jmeter.RandomCSVDataSetConfig
line number         : 360
version             : 5.1 r1853635
-------------------------------
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:459) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.1.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.loadTree(SaveService.java:432) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.1.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.runNonGui(JMeter.java:999) [ApacheJMeter_core-5.1.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startNonGui(JMeter.java:986) [ApacheJMeter_core-5.1.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:563) [ApacheJMeter_core-5.1.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:253) [ApacheJMeter-5.1.jar:5.1 r1853635]
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/com.blazemeter.jmeter.RandomCSVDataSetConfig
line number         : 360
version             : 5.1 r1853635
-------------------------------
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.createConversionException(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:102) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.1.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:96) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.1.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1487) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1467) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1338) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:449) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.1.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : com.blazemeter.jmeter.RandomCSVDataSetConfig
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/com.blazemeter.jmeter.RandomCSVDataSetConfig
line number         : 360
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:77) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readBareItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:132) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:117) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.1.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:94) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.1.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1487) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1467) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1338) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:449) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.1.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.RandomCSVDataSetConfig
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService$XStreamWrapper$1.realClass(SaveService.java:98) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.1.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readBareItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:131) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:117) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.1.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readBareItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:132) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:117) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.1.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:94) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.1.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1487) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1467) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1338) ~[xstream-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:449) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.1.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    ... 9 more
```

**UPDATE:**

I found a way to do it using the documentation for the plugin [here](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-Excluding-libraries-to-from-the-classpath)

Comment: Hello, answer your own question and accept it. So that it helps others. Thanks

Comment: sure thing, that was an easy fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by adding jar's to the /lib/ext directory as the following:

```
+---+
<project>
    [...]
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jmeter.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!--specifying this will make the build fail if the fail percentage is more than that.-->
                <errorRateThresholdInPercent>10</errorRateThresholdInPercent>
                <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
                <propertiesJMeter>
                    <BUILD_TAG>${project.version}</BUILD_TAG>
                    <!--Specifying the number of threads passed to the test plan-->
                    <threads>100</threads>
                    <duration>30</duration>
                </propertiesJMeter>
                <jmeterExtensions>
                    <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.6</artifact>
                    <artifact>com.blazemeter:jmeter-plugins-random-csv-data-set:0.6</artifact>
                </jmeterExtensions>
                <excludedArtifacts>
                    <exclusion>org.slf4j:slf4j-nop</exclusion>
                    <exclusion>avalon-framework:*</exclusion>
                    <exclusion>org.apache.tika:*</exclusion>
                    <exclusion>excalibur-datasource:excalibur-datasource</exclusion>
                    <exclusion>excalibur-instrument:excalibur-instrument</exclusion>
                    <exclusion>excalibur-logger:excalibur-logger</exclusion>
                    <exclusion>excalibur-pool:*</exclusion>
                    <exclusion>org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b5</exclusion>
                </excludedArtifacts>
                <jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m</argument>
                        <argument>-Xmx1024m</argument>
                        <argument>-Xms1024m</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>check-results</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>results</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
    [...]
</project>
+---+
```